# Displaying custom post type listing

Tags: custom-post-types

The following function enables a single custom post type template from a plugin:

```
function ch4_br_template_include( $template_path ) {
           if ( get_post_type() == 'book_reviews' ) {
               if ( is_single() ) {
                   // checks if the file exists in the theme first,
                   // otherwise serve the file from the plugin
                   if ( $theme_file = locate_template( array
                       ( 'single-book_reviews.php' ) ) ) {
                       $template_path = $theme_file;
                   } else {
                       $template_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) .
                           '/single-book_reviews.php';
} }
}
           return $template_path;
       }
```

What is the equivalent for displaying a list of my custom post types? I want to have a separate template for displaying a table of, in my case 'resellers', at mysite/resellers.

Here is my custom post type:

```
public function wps_reseller_cpt() {
        $labels = array(
            'name'               => _x( 'WPS Resellers', 'post type general name' ),
            'singular_name'      => _x( 'WPS Reseller', 'post type singular name' ),
            'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book' ),
            'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Reseller' ),
            'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Reseller' ),
            'new_item'           => __( 'New Reseller' ),
            'all_items'          => __( 'All Resellers' ),
            'view_item'          => __( 'View Reseller' ),
            'search_items'       => __( 'Search Resellers' ),
            'not_found'          => __( 'No resellers found' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Reseller found in the Trash' ),
            'parent_item_colon'  => '',
            'menu_name'          => 'Resellers'
        );
        $args = array(
            'labels'        => $labels,
            'description'   => 'Holds our resellers and reseller specific data',
            'public'        => true,
            'menu_position' => 50,
            'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor','image', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields' ),
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'resellers'),
            'has_archive'   => true,
        );
        register_post_type( 'wps-reseller', $args );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `'single_template'` filter use the more generic `'template_include'` filter for both archive annd single post view:

```
add_filter('template_include', 'my_custom_templates');

function my_custom_templates( $template ) {
  if ( is_single() && ( 'book_reviews' == get_post_type() ) ) {
    if ( ! locate_template('single-book_reviews.php', false) )
       $template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/single-book_reviews.php';
  } elseif( is_post_type_archive('book_reviews') ) {
     if ( ! locate_template('archive-book_reviews.php', false) )
       $template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/archive-book_reviews.php';
  }
  return $template;
}
```

After that you have just to create the file `'archive-book_reviews.php'` in your plugin folder.